# Do you know any e-commerce platform that successfully helps consumers compare different products with infographics

Tags: user-centered-design

When it comes to decide what camera to buy, or any other complex product, within hundreds of other choices, users could use comparison tools to make their decisions. 
Infographics seem a great way to do that and I am studying their role in creating better user experiences when purchasing online. 
Do you know of any existing successful website that helps users with infographics to make a decision online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the product compare feature commonly in ecommerce shops that sell products like computers and phones, where features tend to be a major selling point.

e.g.
http://www.priceme.com.sg/Compare.aspx?t=js&pids=892084945,892804658

If you consider bar graphs to be infographics then this would be an example.

Answer (score 1):

Infographics aren't a great mechanism for this. They don't allow for easy comparison of complex products. Here are some designs that *are* good for this:

**FitBit's [Find Your Fit](https://www.fitbit.com/compare)** for wearable devices

Pros

- Sorts devices by behavior-centric categories: Everyday, Active, and Performance
- Allows selection of devices in order to compare
- Enables effective comparison through visuals

Cons

- Comparison interaction model for devices within lifestyle isn't terribly clear (clicking a device shows its capabilities)
- Photos distract from the comparison
- Different comparison organization for lifestyle and device comparisons (highlighted horizontal list and categories grid with checkboxes, respectively)

**[Google Compare](https://www.google.com/compare/creditcard/)** for credit cards

Pros

- Clear explanations of comparison criteria that users may not understand (Intro purchase APR, Regular APR, and Recommended credit score)
- Enables users to quickly scan option set by effectively combining text and imagery
- Detail views are visible with list view

Cons

- Granular filtering is more difficult than necessary due to the use of radio buttons rather than checkboxes

Hopefully this is helpful. If not, can you provide a more details as to what you're comparing and a rationale as to why you want to use an infographic? Happy to update my answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I am looking for visual representations of data (quantities rather than qualities) that otherwise can be really hard work to read and understand when you want to compare different products

Comment: Quantities of what? That's going to dictate what types of visualizations you use.